# Undefined method `demodulize' for nil:NilClass in AuthLogic application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, jruby, authlogic

I was following a webtutorial on how to make an online app using jruby with a login system. I am new to jruby and I am sorry if I have left out any important information.

I have a `username` model and a `user_login` model with what I think is correct. The error I'm getting is when I try to create a new `user_login` session. Essentially, I can register a user but once my `user_login` controller calls  `@user_login = UserLogin.new`, the system crashes out with the following message:

```
undefined method `demodulize' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/eoin/programming/year/website

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
authlogic (3.3.0) lib/authlogic/session/klass.rb:52:in `initialize'
authlogic (3.3.0) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:79:in `initialize'
app/controllers/user_logins_controller.rb:6:in `new'
org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1659:in `__send__'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2086:in `send'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
...
```

My controller class looks like this:

```
class UserLoginsController < ApplicationController

# GET /user_logins/new
# GET /user_logins/new.json
def new
@user_login = UserLogin.new

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @user_login }
 end
 end



# POST /user_logins
# POST /user_logins.json
def create
@user_login = UserLogin.new(params[:user_login])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user_login.save
     format.html { redirect_to(:usernames, :notice => 'Login Successful') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user_login, :status => :created, :location => @user_login }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user_login.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


# DELETE /user_logins/1
# DELETE /user_logins/1.json
def destroy
@user_login = UserLogin.find
@user_login.destroy

respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to(:usernames, :notice => 'Goodbye!') }
  format.json { head :ok }
end
end
end
```

I am executing the program on ubuntu and have no idea what to do. There appears to be no help online for this problem. Any advice on where to fix this problem would be really appricated.
Thanks

oh here is my gemlock file to see what gems i have installed.

```
     remote: http://rubygems.org/
specs:
  actionmailer (3.2.13)
  actionpack (= 3.2.13)
  mail (~> 2.5.3)
actionpack (3.2.13)
  activemodel (= 3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
  builder (~> 3.0.0)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
  journey (~> 1.0.4)
  rack (~> 1.4.5)
  rack-cache (~> 1.2)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
  sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
  builder (~> 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.2.13)
  activemodel (= 3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
  arel (~> 3.0.2)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.9)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.2.9)
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.2.9)
  jdbc-sqlite3 (~> 3.7.2)
activeresource (3.2.13)
  activemodel (= 3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
  i18n (= 0.6.1)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
arel (3.0.2)
authlogic (3.3.0)
  activerecord (>= 3.2)
  activesupport (>= 2.3)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
builder (3.0.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.1)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.0)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
jruby-openssl (0.8.8)
  bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0147)
json (1.8.0)
json (1.8.0-java)
mail (2.5.4)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.23)
multi_json (1.7.4)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
  rack (>= 0.4)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
  rack
rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (3.2.13)
  actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
  actionpack (= 3.2.13)
  activerecord (= 3.2.13)
  activeresource (= 3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
  actionpack (= 3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
  rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rdoc (~> 3.4)
  thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
  json (~> 1.4)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
  tilt (~> 1.3)
sprockets (2.2.2)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.12)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
```

Please ask and I will put up any additional code.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using the class names provided in the example (seems to be the Authlogic tutorial), then you need to specify with what model it needs to authenticate with, for example:

```
class UserLogin < Authlogic::Session::Base
  authenticate_with Username
end
```

This way you are telling the UserLogin class that it needs to check on the Username model for validating authentication credentials.

You didn't post your model's code, so I'm guessing that's how it's named.